# When to create a copy of the passed in argument inside method and when to not?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

I'm new to Java and I was wondering under what kind of circumstances should we create a copy of the passed in argument inside the method, and when should we not?

Comment: If you're planning on modifying it and the caller is not expecting you to.

Comment: I can't remember the last time I created a copy. Very very rare operation.

Comment: @EJP can you please explain why creating a copy is a very rare operation in a bit more detail? THank you very much for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See there could be n number of scenarios where you can make a copy of the arguments before operating upon them, e.g.

1. Suppose if you want to compare the arguments with final result in method, say if you get a String and in the method make some changes on it and compare for length with passed in argument etc.
2. In case of exception you want to display/return the actual argument back to calling code.
   Similarly there could be a lot of other reasons.

Comment: Strings are immutable.